# query wrt sendto function in socket

Tags: c, sockets, linux-device-driver

I am working with the following API.

```
sendto(dw_SockHdler,b_TxBuff, strlen(b_TxBuff), 0,
              (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
```

the b_TxBuff has to be forcefully declared as char.

I went through the api guide . it seems its a "const void *" so basically i can typecast the void* but this does not allow me giving an error.

is there a work around so that i get flexibility of passing unsigned char buff to this API.

Comment: "* ... it seems its a `const void` *" You mean: "`const void *`", don't you?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to 'typecast the `void*`', which I assume is what you meant, at all. You have to typecast your `char buff[]` *to* `void *` ... but any pointer including the `char *` that you already have in `buff` can automatically be converted to `void *` without the necessity of an explicit cast.

Answer (score -1):

I got work around ... Please confirm is it right way to go,

1. Declaring the unsigned char buff[] = {'\0'};
2. declaring the void *ptr = NULL;
3. Assigning the Pointer the base address of buffer. ptr = buff;
4. passing the ptr to function

   sendto(dw_SockHdler,ptr, 100, 0,
                 (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

Please confirm if any further modifications into this

Comment: If you can do step 3 you can call the function with `buff` directly. The steps required in the compiler are the same.